# opengl - flickering of fragments even with disabled depth test

Tags: opengl, textures, shader

I'm trying to render a quad with a coloured border. I'm using texture coordinates to detect whether the fragment should be considered part of border or not. If it is part of border, then render it with green colour or else with black colour.

Here are my vertices / normals / tex coordinates.

```
    float vertices[] = {
        // posistions          // normals           // texture coords
      -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
       0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
       0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
       0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
      -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
      -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    }
```

Here's my fragment shader

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 frag_pos;
in vec3 frag_nor;
in vec2 frag_tex;

out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
    vec2 origin = vec2(0.01, 0.01);

    float width =  1.0 - origin.x * 2.0;
    float height = 1.0 - origin.y * 2.0;

    if( (frag_tex.x >= origin.x && frag_tex.x < origin.x + width) &&
        (frag_tex.y >= origin.y && frag_tex.y < origin.y + height) )
    {
        frag_color = vec4(0.0);
    }
    else
    {
        frag_color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm rendering

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

[image: GIF LINK]

In right, I'm drawing the same quad with another pass-through fragment shader in wireframe mode.

As you can see the left quad is flickering while moving the camera. Any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Most probably, because lack of resolution/precission, when the quad is getting far away, one pixel holds a range of fragments, and depending on the order of processing, some will be black (if the border ones are processed before the inner ones) and some will be green (if the border is processed after the inner). You should increase the origin vector with a factor that depends on the depth, something like `vec2 origin = vec2(0.01, 0.01) + 0.1 * gl_FragDepth;`. Of course, you need to enable depth test or use the camera space z coordinate

Comment: This seems to be a fairly fragile approach. It is difficult to suggest anything without knowing exactly what you want to achieve. Why not add some geometry and actually draw the border? Why not apply a texture for the whole quad that has a border?

Comment: @J.R. Initially I was using a texture, but it was also having the same problem. I used mipmaps to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exist even with applying a 2D texture. To fix that, I used Mipmaps with these filters.

```
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```